# How to make the mouse stop when moving between screens when they're not aligned in Windows 11?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, windows-11

Back in Windows 10, if you had multiple monitors, your mouse cursor would stop if it tried to leave the move from one screen to another if they were not properly aligned.

I've upgraded to Windows 11, and now regardless of where the cursor is, it will always transfer to the other screen.

Is there a way to restore the Windows 10 behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the article
[Turn On or Off "Ease Cursor Movement between Displays" in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-ease-cursor-movement-between-displays-in-windows-11.4873/).

When this option is turned off, the cursor will stick when dragged
between displays that do not share the same border.

- Run *Settings > System > Display*
- Click on "Multiple displays"
- Uncheck "Ease cursor movement between displays".

The effect should be immediate.

The article also shows how to do the same using the registry.

Comment: Thanks, this Ease Cursor Movement behavior was driving me crazy on my setup with screens of different sizes.